# Python3.7 tkinter how do i find the path to the TCL interpretor used

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7

Due to specific circumstances, I need to find the path for the installed TCL interpreter in python3. Currently, I can see that this package is installed in python3.7/tcl/tcl8.6. Is there a way to get this path during runtime, without calling tkinter.TCL()?

Regards

Comment: Are you looking for the Tcl folder or what ?

Comment: yes. how to resolve the path to the TCL folder that the tkinter uses on windows. right now I'm using : os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), 'tcl/tcl8.6')).replace('\\','/')

Comment: Does importing tkinter and then using `tkinter._tkinter.__file__` do what you want? Are you sure you really need this information? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Bryan tkinter._tkinter.__file__ only gives me 'C:\\Python37\\DLLs\\_tkinter.pyd'. And yes I need this information because I need it to overwrite the TCL interpreter path in another program during runtime.

Comment: That's probably not a good idea. What would be the purpose of it? In any case you should be better with overwriting the existing one.

Comment: @thingamabobs. I have an app that collects a list of files from Quartus TCL scripts or a subset thereof. This is done by parsing them with the tkinter module since it enables me to make python function and parse them into the tcl scripts to overwrite some library specific function. But when this python script is executed inside Riviera-pro. Riviera-rpso own TCL takes over somehow. And requires a specific version. So you get a version clash. So to force the correct version I'm overwriting the "TCL_LIBRARY" environment variable and it works however its hardcoded now.